# In Cluster Analysis, how do we calculate Purity?

Tags: clustering

In cluster analysis how do we calculate purity? What's the equation?

I'm not looking for a code to do it for me.

[image]

Let $\omega_k$ be cluster k, and $c_j$ be class j.

So is purity practically accuracy? it looks like were summing the amount of truly classified class per cluster over the sample size.

[equation source](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html)

The question is what is the relationship between the output and the input?

If there's Truly Positive(TP), Truly Negative (TN), Falsely Positive(FP), Falsely Negative (FN).
Is it $Purity = \frac{TP_K}{(TP+TN+FP+FN)}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out,

Purity is the the accuracy of the most frequent cluster, 
so it the number of occurrences of the most frequent classes / the size of the clusteres (this should be high)